# Select a line in a d3.js or nvd3.js line graph

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

In a D3 or NVD3.js line graph, how can I select a particular line once the graph is rendered? For example, suppose I want to animate the stroke width on a line, like this:

```
d3.selectAll('path').transition().duration(2000).style("stroke-width", "20");
```

The above will select *all* paths, obviously, but I would like to select a particular series—for example, the `Oranges` series in a data set defined like this:

```
var data = [{key: "Apples", values: array1},{key: "Oranges", values: array2}]
```

I thought something this might work, but it did not:

```
d3.select('#chart svg').datum(data[1]).transition... // or alternatively,
d3.select('#chart svg').datum(data[1].values).transition...
```

I've been trying to figure it out using the **Cumulative Line Chart** example in the code editor here, with no success: http://nvd3.org/livecode/#codemirrorNav

This is a very basic question, but I'm new to D3 and have been unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of simple ways that I can think of:

1. You can store each path in its own variable (or inside an array):

   `var path1 = graph.append("g").append("path").data([data1]).attr("class", "line1");`

   Now you can apply your transitions to just this path variable and it should work.
2. Another option is to give each path a unique class and then use d3.selectAll(".uniqueclassname") and apply your transitions.

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/123/), look at the tick function (specially for the following piece of code).

```
// redraw the lines
        graph.select(".line1").attr("d", line).attr("transform", null);
        path2.attr("d", line).attr("transform", null);
        path3.attr("d", line).attr("transform", null);
        graph.select(".line4").attr("d", line).attr("transform", null);
```

Comment: If the path were part of a group with a class, how would I select it? 

By inspecting source on the nvd3.js example I've noticed that the lines are grouped into `<g>`'s with classes, like `.nv-series-0`, `.nv-series-1`, etc. `d3.select('.nv-series-1').style("stroke-width", "20")` did not work.